# Value of published (non-english) books for applying in a PhD program

Tags: publications, phd, cv, books

I have published a scientific book (i.e. a text book) alongside with my supervisor (he is an associate professor, by the way). Since the book is not in English and consequently does not target international audiences, can it provide some remarkable value in my CV for a PhD program abroad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the language matters. It is a substantial achievement, I think. If it is in your field, which I assume, it will have value. But, depending on where you are applying, you will need other things as well. If your contribution was "only" providing exercises, then it might be a bit less, but for content contributions it would be good.

But no one thing is determinative of your suitability for admissions.

Comment: *If* added to the CV, do not forget to include beside the publishers' name the ISBN (e.g., retrieval in https://www.worldcat.org/), or/and the doi (sometimes, chapters in a book have their own doi, e.g., doi 10.1007/978-3-642-04759-6_3 vs. doi 10.1007/978-3-642-04759-6_4).

Comment: Thanks for the answer; do video tutorials - similar to what presented in Udemy- introduce such value as published books?

Comment: Probably not, unless somehow vetted by an external reviewing system that is recognized. Books get reviewed and edited. Maybe tutorials do also, but it is the external review that helps give credence to such work. I didn't separate out self published books in my answer, but it might be similar there unless you can show wide acceptance, even if regional. But they are worth putting on a CV in any case. Especially as they show some commitment.